# Connect to a database conditionally

Tags: perl, if-statement, dbi

I've been having some trouble connecting to my databases using the DBI module. I have a properties file, and in it it specifies whether I want to connect to my oracle or postgres DBs via a simple `database=oracle` or `database=postgres`. My property file is set up using the Config::Tiny module, and my variable are set up as so:

```
my $database = $config->{myDB}->{database};
                       ...
```

What I don't understand is even though this works for all my variables, if I try something like this to connect to whichever database is specified in the properties file...

```
if($database eq "oracle"){
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:host=abc123-server;sid=XE;port=1521","User","Pass");
}
elsif($database eq "postgres"){
    my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=pepperoni;host=789xyz-server;port=5444;","Foo","Bar");
}else{
    print "Could not connect to a database";
}
```

...I end up with these errors:

```
Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name at supportvuloop.pl line 70.
Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name at reportloop.pl line 80.
Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name at reportloop.pl line 81.
Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name at reportloop.pl line 82.
Global symbol "$dbh" requires explicit package name at reportloop.pl line 88.
```

I can connect to either DB just fine when they are not part of an if condition, any ideas why it would cause errors now?

Comment: Why not just put the whole "Oracle:host=abc123-server;sid=XE;port=1521" string in your config file?  That way, you can use any database without changing the code.  For easy switching, put both the Oracle and Postgres lines in the config file, and comment out the one you're not using.

Comment: @cjm - for that matter, have an oracle OR sybase file and switch by reading a different config file name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $dbh variable is not declared in correct scope. You should instead declare it before your "if" statement:

```
my $dbh;

if ($x) {
    $dbh=xxx1;
} elsif ($y) {
    $dbh=xxx2;
} else { # error
}
...
```

They was your code was structured, `$dbh` variable was declared as `my` inside the "if" block (and independently, inside "else" block), and therefore the rest of your code did not see those variables

For further reading:

- [`perldoc my`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html)

Answer (score 3):

DVK already answer your question, but I wanted to give a tip. I would write the code as follows, since it separates configuration from database connection:

```
my %connect_info = (
   "oracle" => {
      dsn      => "dbi:Oracle:host=abc123-server;sid=XE;port=1521",
      user     => "User",
      password => "Pass",
   },
   "postgres" => {
      dsn      => "dbi:Pg:dbname=pepperoni;host=789xyz-server;port=5444;",
      user     => "Foo",
      password => "Bar",
   },
);

my $connect_info = $connect_info{$database}
   or die("Unknown database $database\n");

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
   $connect_info{dsn},
   $connect_info{user},
   $connect_info{password},
);
```

Comment: +1 - didn't want to muddy the waters in my answer with code style, but factoring out like this is an excellent idea.